# Failing to connect to local server with credentials using smbclient

Tags: python, server, raspberry-pi, connection, smb

I am using a Raspberry Pi4 with an installed Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) (Debian) system.

I am trying to use python to read and write files to and from a local server.

```
import smbclient
smbclient.ClientConfig(username = 'TEST', password = 'password')
smbclient.register_session('smb://192.168.119.10/', username = 'TEST', password = 'password')
```

These 3 lines already give me an Errormessage saying:

```
"Failed to connect to '%s:%s': %s" % (self.server, self.port, str(err))) from err ValueError:
Failed to connect to 'smb://192.168.119.10/:445': [Errno -2] Name or service not known.
```

I have been using manual File explorer Systems to connect to the Server IP and the same username + password without a problem. I can't find a solution to get it to work using a python script. I tried other SMB commands aswell without luck.

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace 'smb://192.168.119.10/:445' with '192.168.119.10'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Had similar issue and this solution worked, at least in my case.